# Authentication failure when sending message

Tags: email, powershell

I am trying to send a message with PowerShell but I can not send the message. The error says:

> The server SMTP requires a connection safe or the user didn't authenticate.

I don't know where is my error and I don't know what more I can try.

This is my code:

```
$EmailTo = "prueba@gmail.com"
$EmailFrom = "pacopepe@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Test" 
$Body = "Test Body" 
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("pacopepe@gmail.com", "pacopaco"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

Note: In credentials, I put `$emailfrom` and the password of his mail.

Comment: Have you tried it with `Send-MailMessage`?

Comment: Do you have two factor authorization enabled for your Google account?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, I tried $from = "pacopepe@gmail.com"
$to = "prueba@gmail.com"
$subject = "Test "
$smtpserver = "smtp.gmail.com"
$body = "body"
Send-MailMessage -smtpServer $smtpserver -from $from -to $to -subject $subject -Credential Get-Credential -body $body -UseSsl -Port 465

Comment: @PetSerAl No, I don't have. The error using Send-MailMessage is: "You can not write data to the transport layer".

Comment: @Rubén Which PowerShell version you use? `(New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential UserName@gmail.com,(New-Object Security.SecureString)).GetNetworkCredential()` in PowerShell v2 this code return `UserName=UserName;Domain=gmail.com` which is not correct. You have to write it as this: `New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential \UserName@gmail.com,(New-Object Security.SecureString)` to get correct results.